# Caption above inserted PDF

Tags: floats, captions, pdf, pdfpages

I have inserted a three pages long table in my project. The table was added as a pdf document. Now I would like to insert a caption above the table with `Table A= …`

I have tried to figure it out by myself, using an example I found, but it puts the caption under the table and uses `Figure …`

Here is an example of what it looks now and what I want to accomplish.
[image]

I use the following code to insert the pdf: `\includepdf[pages={1,2,3}]{Vorgeschlagene Versuchsreihen.pdf}`.

Comment: You probably should not be using `\includepdf` if you want to put a PDF into a float. `\includepdf` will replace entire pages. Probably better to use normal `\include` with proper scaling.

Comment: show a small but complete example. You can use `example-image` instead of your own pdf in the example.

Comment: @delaif by \include you mean including the pdf as a figur or what ( am not well experienced with Latex) .

Comment: Sorry my bad, `\includegraphics` (`\include` if for other `.tex` files).

Comment: A caption under the table with "Figure" comes from using the `{figure}` environment, not from `\includepdf`.

Answer (score 1):

- We haven't any information about your document
- Is your table insert as image or is write as table by help of some package?
- In the later case as starting point can serve the following MWE (without coloring of rows):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=25mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-2]
    \begin{center}
    \begin{longtblr}[
caption = {My long table},
  label = {tab:<name>}
                    ]{
    rowhead = 1,
    hlines, vlines,
    colspec = {*{3}{c}X[j] *{3}{c}X[j]},
    row{1}  = {font=\bfseries},
    row{2,3} = {bg=yellow!30},
                     }
text    &   text    &   text    &   text    
        &   text    &   text    &   text    &   text        \\
    1   &   2       &   3       &   4
        &   5       &   6       &   7       &   8           \\       
    1   &   2       &   3       &   \lipsum[66]
        &   5       &   6       &   7       &   8           \\
    1   &   2       &   3       &   4
        &   5       &   6       &   7       &   \lipsum[66] \\
\SetRow{fg=blue}
    1   &   2       &   3       &   \lipsum[66]
        &   5       &   6       &   7       &   8           \\
\SetRow{bg=orange!30}
    1   &   2       &   3       &   4
        &   5       &   6       &   7       &   \lipsum[66] \\
    \end{longtblr}
    \end{center}
\lipsum[4-5]
\end{document}
```

Compiling this MWE gives desired position of table captions:

[image]

**Edit:**
Added two ways how to colored background of rows and text in rows.

Comment: As I understand it, he just includes a pre-compiled PDF (which just happens to be a table, not that it matters.)

Comment: @ingmar yes that is right , I just inserted it as a pre-compiled PDF ( which just happens to be a table ) . Since it is a three pages long table , I can t use the option of inserting it neither as  a figure ( figure won't look good) nor as a table( too much time needed to fill the table, place it  and color it)  .

Comment: @ZARKO The coloring of the table is really important , I need to keep it.

Comment: @AnisFerjani, as I wrote: as starting point ... So far you not provide any information about your document nor about your table (image if table is not sufficient). I'm not willing reproduce it from image from scratch knowing, that you already wrote a table and also apparently you are not willing to share your code with us.

Comment: @zarko am sorry, If I wasn't clear but the only code I used to insert the table is  \usepackage{pdfpages}     \includepdf[pages={1,2,3}]{Vorgeschlagene Versuchsreihen.pdf}. and nothing else.            ( the table described above is a pdf document. Please tell me exactly what informations are needed and I will share willingly .  My question is : is there a way to put the caption above the pdf document.   As I checked there is a way to put a caption under the pdf ( but it will show as caption '' figure x'' ) .  I want to change it to (caption'' table x ") . I hope I clearified the situation.

Comment: @AnisFerjani, sorry, you not make your question more clear. Please edit it and add information to it which we asked for. The most important is MWE, which reproduce your problem.